# How to do gazing on idol to praise a deity?

Tags: vedas, mantras, yoga, tantra, deity

I've heat that in some kind of advanced stage of gazing on Idols or Saints, the deities and saints are
pleased with the sadhaka and that they help him in all ways..
How to do this??